# How to extract any "-letter" combination from a string and put it into its own column?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

If I have an address like the following:

| address |
| --- |
| 1234-C SMITH AVE |

How can I extract the "-C" from the existing string and put "STE C" or "C" into its own column and keep everything else in a separate column?

(not including the portion of the code that pulls through the original address column into address line 1 column if it's NULL. AKA no match was found)
I have the following existing code for similar cases:

```
CASE WHEN
database.table.address LIKE ‘%-[a-zA-Z]%’
THEN
SUBSTR(database.table.address,DECODE(INSTR(database.table.address, ‘-[a-zA-Z]’),0,NULL,INSTR,(database.table.address,‘-[a-zA-Z]’)))

END “address line 2”

CASE WHEN
database.table.address LIKE ‘%-[a-zA-Z]%’
THEN
SUBSTR(database.table.address,0,INSTR(database.table.address, ‘-[a-zA-Z]’)-1)

END “address line 1”
```

My current output is:

| address line 1 |
| --- |
| 1234-C SMITH AVE |

My desired output is:

| address line 1 | address line 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 SMITH AVE | STE C |

or:

| address line 1 | address line 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 SMITH AVE | C |

I think I might not be fully understanding regex since this exact code works if I were to replace -[a-zA-Z] with something like STE (assuming the address has STE in it, it would extract it, PLUS i'm not sure how to separate these columns without pulling everything to the left of the substring im searching on into address line 1 & everything right of the substring im searching on into address line 2.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This returns what you asked for, but - perhaps you should have posted some more examples of what you *have* and what you *want*.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1234-C SMITH AVE' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select regexp_replace(col, '-[[:alpha:]]') line_1,
  4         ltrim(regexp_substr(col, '-[[:alpha:]]'), '-') line_2
  5  from test;

LINE_1         LINE_2
-------------- -------
1234 SMITH AVE C

SQL>
```